# How to query for deeply nested parent properties with Sequelize in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Using Sequelize (postgres) in a NodeJS app, need the following nested data structure where on the lowest level it only should only include ShortTermGoals where the MidtermGoalId matches the parent MidtermGoal id.

```js
const db = require('../../db/models');

db.Policies.findAll({
      include: [
        {
          model: db.Priorities,
          as: 'Priorities',
          include: [
            {
              model: db.MidtermGoals,
              as: 'MidtermGoals',
              include: [
                {
                  model: db.Agencies,
                  as: 'Agencies',
                  include: [
                    {
                      model: db.Divisions,
                      as: 'Divisions',
                      include: [
                        {
                          model: db.ShortTermGoals,
                          as: 'ShortTermGoals',
                          where: { MidtermGoalId: { $col: 'MidtermGoals.id' } }, // <--
                          include: [
                            {
                              model: db.Actions,
                              as: 'Actions',
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          model: db.Activities,
                          as: 'Activities',
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
      ],
    });
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is just a quess but I think your where clause should be at the same level as the "MidtermGoals".